# it compiles but when i submit it says code is wrong

Tags: php, string

**Question:** A string is said to be complete if it contains all the characters from a to z. Given a string, check if it complete or not.

***Input***
First line of the input contains the number of strings N. It is followed by N lines each contains a single string.

***Output***
For each test case print "YES" if the string is complete, else print "NO"

***Constraints***
1 <= N <= 10
The length of the string is at max 100 and the string contains only the characters a to z

YOU CAN CHECK HERE http://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/complete-string-4/

When i submit the PHP code , it shows the result is **wrong**

```
<?php

$allowedString = array('random','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z');

function execute($fileName = "3\nwyyga\nqwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm\nejuxggfsts"){
    global $allowedString;


    //$handle = fopen($fileName, 'r');
    $l=0;
    $text = array();


        $text = explode("\n", $fileName);

    $z=0;
    //  print_r($text);
    if ($text[0]>=1 && $text[0]<=10){
        for($i=1;$i<=$text[0];$i++){

            if(strlen($text[$i])>=26 && strlen($text[$i])<=100 ){
                $count = 0;
                for($z=1;$z<27;$z++){
                    $pos = strpos($text[$i], $allowedString[$z]);
                            if($pos === false){
                                continue;
                            }else{
                                $count++;
                            }


                }
                if($count == 26){
                    echo 'YES'."<br>";
                }else{
                    echo 'NO'."<br>";
                }
            }else{
                    echo 'NO'."<br>";
                }
        }

    }




}

execute();

?>
```

Comment: What is wrong?  Are you seeing errors?

Comment: it doesn` show errors, when i click comple and test it works but when i submit it uses test input from the website and shows it`s wrong for all the 10 inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick look at the page, it seems that the site is STDIO (Standard Input/Output) for input and output data rather than files. So, you shouldn't read/write data to a file.

Here is some code:

```
<?php
    //This will input a file from Standard Input 
    $line = trim(fgets(STDIN));

    //This will output the string to Standard Output
    fwrite(STDOUT, $output);
?>
```

Comment: I haven`t used STDIO before , if you could tell me where changes need to be made in my code ? i knew it has something to do with that but couldn`t figure out

Comment: When you use `$line = trim(fgets(STDIN));` you will get lines one after another from Sample Input